# show data in query oracle but not include duplicate data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

Can you help me, i have problem with my query.
i have data like bellow :

```
+------------+---------+-----+
|    Date    | Prod_ID | Qty |
+------------+---------+-----+
| 01/02/2018 | Pencil  |   2 |
| 01/02/2018 | pencil  |   3 |
| 01/02/2018 | pencil  |   4 |
| 01/02/2018 | book    |   5 |
| 01/02/2018 | ruller  |   1 |
+------------+---------+-----+
```

but my result as bellow

```
+------------+---------+-----+
|    Date    | Prod_ID | Qty |
+------------+---------+-----+
| 01/02/2018 |       5 |  15 |
+------------+---------+-----+
```

i need my result bellow

```
+------------+---------+-----+
|    Date    | Prod_ID | Qty |
+------------+---------+-----+
| 01/02/2018 |       3 |  15 |
+------------+---------+-----+
```

bellow my query script

```
select "date",
    Prod_ID,
    Qty,
from data
group by "date",
    Prod_ID,
    Qty,
order by "date";
```

Thank You,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
select "date",
    Count(Distinct Prod_ID) as total_product_count,
    Sum(Qty) as qty
from 
    data
group by 
    "date"
order by "date";
```

Comment: sorry i forget, i need in row Prod_ID as count. but there i found problem it count all data with duplicate

Comment: I edited the query according to your comment. Let me know if this helps.